# R: Create a factor variable based on generic rolling deciles as dataset grows

Tags: r, factors

I can create a factor variable for the deciles of my data using the code below, which takes into account the whole history:

```
`q <- quantile(x, seq(0,1,0.1), na.rm = TRUE)
decilab <- c("1st","2nd","3rd","4th","5th","6th","7th","8th","9th","10th")
q.factor <- cut(x, unique(q), included.lowest = TRUE, labels = decilab)`
```

However, I need to make a generic cut into deciles on a rolling basis, only accounting for the history that is prior to the point being labeled. This code below uses a `for` loop to calculate rolling `quantile` as 9 distinct variables, but I'm not sure how to translate that into a single factor variable (nor do I particularly want/need these variables to exist).

```
`for(i in 1:length(x)){
   D1[i] <- quantile(x[1:i],0.1, na.rm = TRUE)
   D2[i] <- quantile(x[1:i],0.2, na.rm = TRUE)
   D3[i] <- quantile(x[1:i],0.3, na.rm = TRUE)
   D4[i] <- quantile(x[1:i],0.4, na.rm = TRUE)
   D5[i] <- quantile(x[1:i],0.5, na.rm = TRUE)
   D6[i] <- quantile(x[1:i],0.6, na.rm = TRUE)
   D7[i] <- quantile(x[1:i],0.7, na.rm = TRUE)
   D8[i] <- quantile(x[1:i],0.8, na.rm = TRUE)
   D9[i] <- quantile(x[1:i],0.9, na.rm = TRUE)
}`
```

There has to be a better way! Thank you for your help, and my apologies if this is a common problem - I haven't found anything so far.

Edit: Apologies as I am new to Stack Overflow and R. I think I have a better example, but I'm not sure how to resubmit this question.

Suppose you have the vector `x <- 1:1000` the goal is to cut this data into deciles with `cut(x, seq(0,1,0.1), include.lowest = TRUE)` however this would cut the whole series `x` into groups that bucket `[0,100), [100, 200)...etc` however, my goal is that the bucketing is variable, based on only the preceding data, not the whole vector. So essentially, each and every single point would be in the "top decile" because this series is linear, however for a stochastic series the decile of the latest point is only determined relative to proceeding points, not the whole series.

I tried the following:

```
`for (i in 1:length(x)){
    z[i] <- as.numeric(cut(x[1:i], quantile(x[1:i], seq(0,1,.1))))[i]
 } `
```

However that doesn't work

Comment: When asking a question on Stack Overflow about code please provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example including data. In the `r` tag description it specifically requests that you share the necessary data using `dput()`. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: As written this does not make any sense to me. Quantiles are for continuous values, factora are for discrete values. I suggest you try creating an example with a small dataset of whatever sort of variable is imagined and then demonstrate what you expect from it using tertiles.

Comment: The goal is to have the "decile" that is assigned to the x[n] be based on the range of data in x[1:n] and excluding the data in the range of x[(n+1):inf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`library(dplyr)
x <- 1:1000
y<-vector(mode="numeric",length=0)
for (i in 1:length(x)){
   y[i]<-last(ntile(x[1:i],10))
}`
```

This appears to work!

Advice from a colleague was that `dplyr::ntile` was superior to `cut`